# Does PhpStan and Psalm measures cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: php, static-analysis, phpstan, phpmd, psalm-php

I've read the documentation from PhpStan and Psalm, and i couldn't find the rules where it checks the Cyclomatic Complexity like Phpmd does [here](https://phpmd.org/rules/codesize.html#cyclomaticcomplexity)

Also, is it possible to cusomise rules within levels for PhpStan and Psalm? Looking for a source.

Comment: PHPStan does not check cyclomatic complexity but [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) does, there's a sniff called `Generic.Metrics.CyclomaticComplexity` with configurable trigger levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psalm has a ComplexMethod check. Internally, it uses two metrics for this: "method graph size" and "average path length". Not sure if that corresponds to the cyclomatic complexity though

Comment: can you please share more details? on which level psalm does that and which rule is that?

Comment: It is opt-in. You can enable it in `psalm.xml` by adding the `limitMethodComplexity="true"` attribute to the root `<psalm>` element.